# Guzzle post with cookie and data

Tags: php, curl, guzzle6

Current curl format

```
curl -v --cookie "JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxx" -X POST --data "[\"test\",\"password\"]" http://domain.com/register
```

How do I validate cookie & post the data using Guzzle?

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/register';
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();
$register = $client->post($url, ['cookies' => $jar, 'http_errors' => false]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [form_params](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params) request option to post data.
Use [debug](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#debug) request option to compare your request from Guzzle to the curl request.

There are plenty of examples within SO and the Guzzle documentation explains things very well.